# TortoiseHg - Dialogs not appearing or very delayed until appearing but only when accessing repository on mapped drive

Tags: windows-xp, tortoise-hg

On some of our workstations tortoises commit dialogs and repository browsers are not appearing or appear, but after great delay on files from the mapped drive. What might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a network issue more than a TortoiseHg issue.

However, I do vaguely recall a problem with file overlays on TortoiseSVN with network files causing noticeable delays.

If you turn off file overlays, does that fix the problem?